# How to give access of cloud firestore to users in such a way that they are indirectly part of my application but not enrolled in my firebase console?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Basically I'm designing an **angular 7** application where each users can read and write what's inside firestore and for that I have referred their official doc in [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). So I need to fetch data in such a way that whenever a user enters my application he/she should be already authenticated and only then access the cloud firestore data. I'm able to do that in this way:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I'm authenticating with `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` and `GoogleAuthProvider()`.

```
doGoogleLogin() {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('profile');
    provider.addScope('email');
    this.afAuth.auth
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(res => {
      resolve(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}

doLogin(value) {
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
    .then(res => {
      resolve(res);
      console.log(this.afAuth);
    }, err => reject(err));
  });
}
```

What I want is to give users access based on `databaseURL` and `projectId` who are not included in list of users in my firebase console but are already signed-in via email in browser. I know it may sound a little odd despite of the fact that I can authenticate via these methods but the limitation is the number of users in console which can be **maximum of 500**. So the main thing is can I get and use that session token and send it inside to firebase to fetch the data?

I have already tried to define rules in different way but none of them seems to be working. I also went ahead to see if I can provide access to only users of my domain but apparently that's just not way it works because spam users can send same parameters and thus the main purpose is destroyed.
If you need any more clarity with the question please do ask.
Thanks for your help and time. Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, with Firebase security rules, to apply per-user control of data to people who are not signed in with Firebase Authentication.  There is simply no mechanism available to security rules to determine who can do what, if their identity isn't verified by Auth.  Browser cookies are not available.  Anyone who is not signed in will effectively cause `request.auth` to equal null when they try to access documents from mobile clients.

Comment: Okay then, do we have any alternative approach to the same problem like we don't have users but what we have is their oauth token when they logged in for first time via google and sent the same object as a request parameter...?

Comment: No, there are currently no alternatives with security rules.  You could set up your own backend service to manage all this.